# Wordpress Control Panel

Tags: wordpress

I want to load some custom message in the dashboard area (instead of the post/comment information)of wordpress **admin panel**.Anybody can help me........please
The area which start like;
*At a Glance
1   Post    1   Comment
1   Page    1   Approved
1   Category    0   Pending
0   Tags    0   Spam
Change ThemeTheme Thesis with 0 Widgets
You are using WordPress 2.9.2.*

Comment: Please be more specific where you want to place the custom message, and under which conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dashboard editor seems to be broken for newer wp versions.

alternative (when you're into coding) is to create your own dashboard widget. [this page on wordpress.org explains](http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API) how and provides a some (basic) examples.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the wordpress plugins. something like this might help:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-dashboard-editor/